# Adding Button in standard form in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Hi i am trying to add a button in a standard form by using a user event triggered function but it didn't alert me.

```
function clickMe() {
    alert('Button was clicked from "+nlapiGetRecordType()+" in VIEW mode');
}

function myBeforeLoad(type, form, request) {
    var customButton=form.addButton('custpage_mybutton','MyFirstButton','clickMe();');
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your `clickMe` function defined in your User Event or your Client script? In order to be executed from a button click, the function must exist on the client side, so you need to define it in a client script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach your script to the form. You can do this by using form.setScript(nlapiGetExecutionContext().getScriptId());

Answer (score 2):

The script needs to be applied to the form before you create the button and set the function you want to call from the ClientScript.

```
if (type == 'view')
    {
       form.setScript('customscript_asw_ss_cs_member');
       form.addButton('custpage_mybutton','MEMBERSCRIPT','onclick_callAlert()');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While generally the better way to do this is with a separate client script like the other answers, for a simple one-liner you can get away with hard coding the script into a string, e.g.

```
function myBeforeLoad(type, form, request) {
    var script = "alert(\'Button was clicked from \' + nlapiGetRecordType() + \' in VIEW mode\');";
    var customButton = form.addButton('custpage_mybutton','MyFirstButton',script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is user event script
`function myBeforeLoad(type, form) {
        if (type=='view'){

        var customButton = form.addButton('custpage_mybutton','MEMBER SCRIPT','onclick_callAlert()');
      form.setScript('customscript_asw_ss_cs_member');
    }
    }`

This is Client Script

`function onclick_callAlert() 
{
alert('hi');
}`

Thanks For You All Replies....